# Is there any way to fill in up to a limit number of consecutive NA?

Tags: r, data.table, na

I would to fill in up to let's say 3 consecutive NAs in r.  I want to fill in even those that reach the limit point, but just to fill in up to 3 consecutive NAs. For instance. Let's say that I have the following object:

```
x<-c(1.6533926 , 1.9263536 ,  NA , NA, 0.6378220, -0.1162299, -0.5909386, -0.4997750,  0.2603278,  0.8183298, NA, NA, NA,NA,NA,NA)
```

I know that there is a function called na.locf, with the option maxgap. Though, maxgap discards those cases where the number of consecutive nas reached a limit.

```
na.locf(y, maxgap=3)
```

I would like instead to fill in up to 3 consecutive NAs. Then I should have the following. Aditionally. I would like to keep the NAs that are not fill in.

```
y<-c(1.6533926 , 1.9263536 ,  1.9263536 ,1.9263536, 0.6378220, -0.1162299, -0.5909386, -0.4997750,  0.2603278,  0.8183298, 0.8183298, 0.8183298, 0.8183298,NA,NA,NA)
```

In addition I would like to specify that I am using this in the context of a data table. Where my original code looks in the following way:

```
df[, lapply(.SD, function(x){na.locf(x,na.rm=FALSE)})]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes you are right! I haven't seen that answer, as I got all the time the answer with maxgap. Thank you!